# PHP geoplugin failing on public server

Tags: php, geolocation

```
$location  = "http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=115.67.131.206";
$geoplugin = unserialize(file_get_contents($location));
$country   = $geoplugin['geoplugin_countryName'];
$city      = $geoplugin['geoplugin_city'];
```

I am running the above PHP code (from an example by Geoplugin) on IIS and it works perfectly, returning country & city; however when run from a public hosting server nothing is returned and no errors shown. What am I missing?

Comment: Check your configuration http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: Add this code at the beginning and run again. `error_reporting(-1); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);` You'll see the error

Answer (score 0):

Find php.ini on your server and then look for allow_url_fopen make it

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Please let us know if this solve your problem or something else

Comment: I have just checked the server again and have been told that remote connections are not allowed, so presumably this is the reason? I do not have access to the php.ini file.

Comment: i think with shared hostings you still can have your own php.ini file, try creating php.ini file in your root folder add some config to check if server sees it, add allow_url_fopen = On then